# UML State Machines: Local Transitions

Tags: uml, transition, state-machine

According to the state machine below shown in chapter *9.3.3.6 Transition 011-C* of the document *Precise Semantics of UML State Machines* from OMG it's fine to define a local transition from a substate to a containing state.

[image]

But what does that local transition T1.3 do when it's executed? I supposed that state S1.2 is left and after that the default entry of state S1 is applied, hence transition T1.1 is executed and finally state S1.1 is entered.

However, the run-to-completion steps table of that chapter shows that after transition 1.3 is executed, the completion event CE is generated and thus the state S1 is left by transition T3:

[image]

This left me puzzling, as the *UML specification 2.5.1* states in chapter *14.2.3.8.3 Completion Transitions and completion events* that a completion event of a composite state like S1 is only generated if all it's orthogonal regions have reached a final state. This certainly is not the case in the state machine shown above.

Now, which behavior is correct? May it be that the run-to-completion steps table is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The shown sub-state machine uses a so-called local transition (see the link in @Roman's comment). UML 2.5.1 describes a local transition on p. 314

> kind = **local** is the opposite of external, meaning that the Transition does not exit its containing State (and, hence, the exit Behavior of the containing State will not be executed). However, for **local** Transitions the target Vertex must be different from its source Vertex. A **local** Transition can only exist within a composite State.

Examples of local transitions can be found on pp. 334 of the UML 2.5.1 specs.

So the sub-state machine will never exit and thus table and diagram do not match. Likely the author made a mistake and meant what I stated in my original answer below.

**Original answer**:
I never have seen the notation above, but assume that it should picture a sub-state exit (so **T3** will be the next transition which complies with the table).

I guess the notation should rather be using a `Final` like this

[image]

shown in fig. 14.38 on p. 339 of the UML 2.5.1 specs.

Comment: Yes, if that's the intended behavior, the transition T1.3 definitely should point to a final state.

Comment: However, according to the [wikipedia page on UML state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) local transitions from a substate to a containing state are possible. Is that true and if so, what's the behavior if such a transition is executed?

Comment: This notation matches the table, but it is a different state machine!

Comment: @Roman You are right. I found the respective chapter 14.2.3.8.1 in UML 2.5.1, though I haven't dug through to the notation (which is present in the 2.2 specs). I'll try to grasp the whole thing and make an edit.

Comment: @DrP3pp3r Yes, it's likely an error the book editor made. I have updated my answer also according to Roman's comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I supposed that state S1.2 is left and after that the default entry of
>   state S1 is applied, hence transition T1.1 is executed and finally
>   state S1.1 is entered.

"T1.3" should lead to "S1.2" being left, "S1" remains active. "S1" is not left and not re-entred because "T1.3" is a local transition.

The only region of "S1" is not finished as no Final State was entered. Thus no completion transition.

> May it be that the run-to-completion steps table is wrong?

Yes, I believe it is wrong.

Comment: So after state S1.2 is left, will transition T1.1 from the initial state to state S1.1 be executed? Because if no simple state is active it wouldn't be a _stable state configuration_, right?

Comment: No, the initial transition is not taken, because S1 is not entered.  And yes, it is in a stable state configuration. S1 is active and no further transitions have to be taken. The state configuration thus just contains S1.
A state can be active without a child state being active (in all or some of its regions). The same can happen if you do not have an initial pseudostate in a region and you have an transition targeting the composite state containing this region- which is legal.

Comment: Regarding your last statement, the UML specification actually says in chapter *14.2.3.4.5 Entering a State* that "if no initial Pseudostate is defined, there is no single approach defined. One alternative is to treat
such a model as ill formed. A second alternative is to treat the composite State as a simple State, terminating
the traversal on that State despite its internal parts."

Comment: @Roman: Thanks I forgot about that part. Still I do not see the advantage of treating it as ill-formed from a technical point of view. It does not break any algorithms involving transition calculation neither does it make algorithms more complex. It's just an artificial restriction. For a designer it might be a problem if she just forgot an initial transition. But if you forget any element in a state machine it is just broken. That's why you write tests, right?

Comment: I did reflect on the state machine *9.3.3.6 Transition 011-C* again. If one is supposed to treat a composite state as a simple state if it's the target of a transition terminating on its outer edge and there is no initial pseudostate, then maybe one should do the same if a local transition terminates on the inner edge of a composite state. If that's the case, the completion event indeed would be generated after state S1 is reached and the run-to-completion table would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This topic still did bother me despite your appreciated answers, thus I did some further study. On page 31 of the document *Precise Semantics of UML State Machines* I found this:

> Completion of a region activation
>
> RegionActivations never reach completion by being exited either
>   implicitly or explicitly. There are two ways to complete the execution
>   of a region.
>
> 1. The general rule is that a RegionActivation can only complete if a
>      FinalStateActivation (see 8.5.5) for a FinalState owned by the
>      Region is executed. This leads the RegionActivation to be marked as
>      being completed (its isCompleted attribute is set to true).
> 2. **The above general rule is violated only in the situation where a
>      VertexActivation owned by a RegionActivation is exited and the
>      TransitionActivation that exits that VertexActivation has as its
>      target the StateActivation owning the RegionActivation. In this
>      case, and only in this case, does the RegionActivation that owns the
>      exited VertexActivation complete.**

If I'm understanding this correctly, then rule 2 describes exactly the behavior of the state machine *9.3.3.6 Transition 011-C* and in that case the run-to-completion table is actually correct.

Comment: The terms `Region`- and  `VertexActivation` are not defined in the UML specs. So that runs out to an invention of the author.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The quote is from the document _Precise Semantics of UML State Machines_ from _OMG_, which defines execution semantics for UML state machines. It helps to clear things left unclear by the UML specifications. Actually it makes perfect sense to me that a region completes in the case above. As stated below, the state S1 in the example of my question would be the only active one after transition T1.3 if there were no completion transition, so why should the region not complete?

Comment: I see. This is a beta 1.0 document and refers to executable state machines. Honestly, this is a very complex area and I have been working only on "ordinary human manageable" level. OMG might or might not decide to unify their documents. I can only speak for the UML specs.